# how can I save the recyclerview scroll position?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, fragment

fragment_gelocalized.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/ef_circular_progress_bar"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/layoutHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    TabLayout tabLayout;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabsHome(CalmettaRG, CalmettaBD); 

    }

    // Tabs inizio
    public void tabsHome (Typeface CalmettaRG, Typeface CalmettaBD){

        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tab_container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        String[] listTab = {
                "0:Vicino a te:active",
                "1:Consigliati:0"
        };

        for (String string: listTab) {
            String[] parts = string.split(":");
            Integer id = Integer.valueOf(parts[0]);
            String name = parts[1];
            String active = parts[2];
            TextView textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_title,null);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(id).setCustomView(textView);
            TabLayout.Tab singleTab = tabLayout.getTabAt(id);
            if(active.equals("active")) {
                textView.setTypeface(CalmettaBD);
                singleTab.select();
            } else {
                textView.setTypeface(CalmettaRG);
            }
            singleTab.setText(name);
        }

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                Typeface CalmettaBD = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/calmetta_trial/Calmetta_Trial_Bd.ttf");
                Log.wtf("Tuttimenu MainActivity", "onTabSelected: ");
                int tabCount = tabLayout.getTabCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
                    View tabView = tab != null ? tab.getCustomView() : null;
                    if (tabView instanceof TextView) {
                        ((TextView) tabView).setTypeface(CalmettaBD);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                Typeface CalmettaRG = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/calmetta_trial/Calmetta_Trial_Rg.ttf");
                Log.wtf("Tuttimenu MainActivity", "onTabUnselected: ");
                int tabCount = tabLayout.getTabCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
                    View tabView = tab != null ? tab.getCustomView() : null;
                    if (tabView instanceof TextView) {
                        ((TextView) tabView).setTypeface(CalmettaRG);
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }
        });

    }

    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new GeolocalizedFragment());
        adapter.addFragment(new RecommendedFragment());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    // Tabs fine

}
```

GeolocaliedFragment:

```
public class GeolocalizedFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    View view;
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    String urlSite = mainActivity.getGlobalUrlSite();
    Context context;

    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

    GetMenuHomeTaskWeb getMenuHome;
    GPSTraker gpsTraker;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private List<Menu> myDataset = new ArrayList<Menu>();
    JSONArray menus;
    JSONObject listMenus;
    boolean flagDecoration = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        String greeting = (savedInstanceState != null) ? savedInstanceState.getString("greeting") : "null";
        Log.i("Tuttimenu", " onCreate: " + greeting);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context = getActivity();

        Bundle update = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        if(update != null) {
            Log.wtf("Tuttimenu HomeFragment", update.getString("EXTRA_UPDATE"));
        }

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_geolocalized, container, false);

        Typeface CalmettaRG = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/calmetta_trial/Calmetta_Trial_Rg.ttf");
        Typeface CalmettaBD = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/calmetta_trial/Calmetta_Trial_Bd.ttf");

        /*TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_txt1);
        title.setTypeface(CalmettaBD);
        TextView subtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_txt2);
        subtitle.setTypeface(CalmettaRG);*/

        // SwipeRefreshLayout
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary,
                android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);

        // Controllo se esistono menu nel db locale
        DatabaseHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        List<MenuLocal> menuLocalItems  = database.listAllMenuLocal();
        if(menuLocalItems.isEmpty()) {
            // scarico e salvo i menu nel db locale
            getMenu();
        } else {
            // utilizzo i menu del db locale
            getMenuLocal();
        }

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        Log.wtf("Tuttimenu HomeFragment", "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");

        // scarico e salvo i menu nel db locale
        getMenu();

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do something after 100ms
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 2000);

    }

    public void getMenu(){

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(SwipeRefreshLayout.GONE);
        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);

        gpsTraker = new GPSTraker(context);
        getMenuHome = new GetMenuHomeTaskWeb();

        if(gpsTraker.canGetLocation()) {
            double latitude = gpsTraker.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gpsTraker.getLongitude();
            String stringLat = Double.toString(latitude);
            String stringLng = Double.toString(longitude);
            Log.wtf("Tuttimenu GetMenuHome", "lat: " + stringLat + "lng: " + stringLng);
            getMenuHome.setContext(context, "geolocalized", stringLat, stringLng);
        } else {
            gpsTraker.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        gpsTraker.stopUsingGPS();

        try {
            String result = getMenuHome.execute(urlSite).get();

            // TODO da inserire una variale php che restituisce 0 result;
            if(!result.isEmpty()) {

                DatabaseHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                database.setMenuLocal(new MenuLocal(result));

                getHome(result);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(SwipeRefreshLayout.VISIBLE);
                mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getMenuLocal(){

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(SwipeRefreshLayout.GONE);
        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);

        DatabaseHelper database = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        MenuLocal menuLocal = database.selectMenuLocal(1);
        //Log.wtf("Tuttimenu GetMenuHomeLocal", menuLocal.getHome());

        getHome(menuLocal.getHome());
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(SwipeRefreshLayout.VISIBLE);
        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
    }

    private void getHome(String result){

        //Log.wtf("Tuttimenu GetMenuHome", "getHome: " + result);

        try {
            myDataset.clear();

            listMenus = new JSONObject(result);
            int x = listMenus.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
                menus = new JSONArray(listMenus.getString("home"));
                int y = menus.length();
                for (int a = 0; a < y; a++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) menus.get(a);
                    //Log.wtf("Tuttimenu GetMenuHome", jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    myDataset.add(new Menu(jsonObject.getInt("id"), jsonObject.getInt("id_type"),
                            jsonObject.getString("name"), jsonObject.getString("activity_name"),
                            jsonObject.getString("image"), jsonObject.getString("activity_image"),
                            jsonObject.getString("likes"), jsonObject.getString("views")));
                }
            }

            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.layoutHome);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            /*mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            mRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);*/
            /*mRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);*/
            mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            if(!flagDecoration)
            {
                int spacingInPixels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing);
                mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(spacingInPixels));
                //mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                flagDecoration = true;
            }

            mAdapter = new MyAdapterHome((ArrayList<Menu>) myDataset, context);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        } catch (Throwable t) {

            Log.wtf("Tuttimenu GetMenuHome", "Error mAdapter");
            //Log.wtf("Tuttimenu GetMenuHome JSON", "Impossibile analizzare array JSON getHome: \"" + result + "\"");
            //Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Impossibile analizzare array JSON getHome: \"" + result + "\"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        private int halfSpace;

        public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
            this.halfSpace = space / 2;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

            if (parent.getPaddingLeft() != halfSpace) {
                parent.setPadding(halfSpace, halfSpace, halfSpace, halfSpace);
                parent.setClipToPadding(false);
            }

            outRect.top = halfSpace;
            outRect.bottom = halfSpace;
            outRect.left = halfSpace;
            outRect.right = halfSpace;
        }
    }
}
```

MyAdapterHome:

```
public class MyAdapterHome extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Menu> mDataset;
    private Context context;

    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    String urlSite = mainActivity.getGlobalUrlSite();

    public MyAdapterHome(ArrayList<Menu> mDataset, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mDataset = mDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
        // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
        Menu menu = mDataset.get(position);
        return menu.getId_type();
    }

    ViewHolder vh;
    ViewHolderADS vhads;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext () );

        switch (viewType){
            case 9:
                View cardADS = ( View ) mInflater.inflate ( R.layout.card_ads, parent, false );
                vhads = new ViewHolderADS(cardADS);
                return vhads;
            default:
                View cardMenu = ( View ) mInflater.inflate ( R.layout.card_menu, parent, false );
                vh = new ViewHolder(cardMenu);
                return vh;
        }

    }

    ViewHolder ViewHolder;
    ViewHolderADS ViewHolderADS;
    Resources resources;
    Typeface CalmettaTrialLight, CalmettaRG, CalmettaBD;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        getItemViewType(position);
        Menu menu = mDataset.get(position);

        CalmettaTrialLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(holder.itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/calmetta_trial/Calmetta_Trial_Lt.ttf");
        CalmettaRG = Typeface.createFromAsset(holder.itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/calmetta_trial/Calmetta_Trial_Rg.ttf");
        CalmettaBD = Typeface.createFromAsset(holder.itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/calmetta_trial/Calmetta_Trial_Bd.ttf");

        switch (menu.getId_type()){
            case 1:
                ViewHolder = (ViewHolder)holder;
                viewHolder(ViewHolder, menu);
                setTemplateMenu(ViewHolder, "Menù", "ef_menu_shadow", "ic_menu_white", menu, resources);
                break;
            case 2:
                ViewHolder = (ViewHolder)holder;
                viewHolder(ViewHolder, menu);
                setTemplateMenu(ViewHolder, "Vini", "ef_wine_shadow", "ic_wine_white", menu, resources);
                break;
            case 3:
                ViewHolder = (ViewHolder)holder;
                viewHolder(ViewHolder, menu);
                setTemplateMenu(ViewHolder, "Birre", "ef_beers_shadow", "ic_beers_white", menu, resources);
                break;
            case 4:
                ViewHolder = (ViewHolder)holder;
                viewHolder(ViewHolder, menu);
                setTemplateMenu(ViewHolder, "Cocktails", "ef_cocktails_shadow", "ic_cocktails_white", menu, resources);
                break;
            case 5:
                ViewHolder = (ViewHolder)holder;
                viewHolder(ViewHolder, menu);
                setTemplateMenu(ViewHolder, "Dolci", "ef_dessert_shadow", "ic_dessert_white", menu, resources);
                break;
            case 6:
                ViewHolder = (ViewHolder)holder;
                viewHolder(ViewHolder, menu);
                setTemplateMenu(ViewHolder, "Asporto", "ef_takeaway_shadow", "ic_takeaway_white", menu, resources);
                break;
            case 7:
                ViewHolder = (ViewHolder)holder;
                viewHolder(ViewHolder, menu);
                setTemplateMenu(ViewHolder, "Delivery", "ef_delivery_shadow", "ic_delivery_white", menu, resources);
                break;
            case 8:
                ViewHolder = (ViewHolder)holder;
                viewHolder(ViewHolder, menu);
                setTemplateMenu(ViewHolder, "All You Can Eat", "ef_allyoucaneat_shadow", "ic_allyoucaneat_white", menu, resources);
                break;
            case 9:
                ViewHolderADS = (ViewHolderADS)holder;
                viewHolderADS(ViewHolderADS, menu);
                //TODO da sistemare il codice per la visulizzazione delle promozioni "Banner"
                break;
            case 10:
                //TODO inserite grafica del menu vetrina
                ViewHolder = (ViewHolder)holder;
                viewHolder(ViewHolder, menu);
                setTemplateMenu(ViewHolder, "Vetrina", "ef_allyoucaneat_shadow", "ic_allyoucaneat_white", menu, resources);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void viewHolderADS(ViewHolderADS holder, Menu menu){
        String replacedStringADS = urlSite.replace("/index.php", "/images");
        String imagePathADS = replacedStringADS + "/menus/" + menu.getImagePath();
        PicassoCache.getPicassoInstance(ViewHolderADS.imageMenu.getContext()).load(imagePathADS).into(ViewHolderADS.imageMenu);
        resources = holder.itemView.getResources();
    }

    public void viewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final Menu menu){
        String replacedString = urlSite.replace("/index.php", "/images");
        String imagePath = replacedString + "/menus/" + menu.getImagePath();
        String imageActivityPath = replacedString + "/activity/logo/" + menu.getImageActivityPath();
        PicassoCache.getPicassoInstance(ViewHolder.imageMenu.getContext()).load(imagePath).into(ViewHolder.imageMenu);
        PicassoCache.getPicassoInstance(ViewHolder.imageMenu.getContext()).load(imageActivityPath).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(ViewHolder.imgCorners);
        //Picasso.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(replacedString + mDataset.get(position)).into(holder.imageView);
        Typeface CalmettaTrialLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(holder.itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/calmetta_trial/Calmetta_Trial_Lt.ttf");
        Typeface CalmettaRG = Typeface.createFromAsset(holder.itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/calmetta_trial/Calmetta_Trial_Rg.ttf");
        Typeface CalmettaBD = Typeface.createFromAsset(holder.itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/calmetta_trial/Calmetta_Trial_Bd.ttf");
        ViewHolder.mTitle.setTypeface(CalmettaBD);
        ViewHolder.mTitle.setText(menu.getNameActivity());
        /*holder.mTitle.setSingleLine(true);
        holder.mTitle.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);*/
        ViewHolder.mSubTitle.setTypeface(CalmettaRG);
        resources = holder.itemView.getResources();


        holder.txtLikes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.wtf("Tuttimenu MyAdapterHome", "Click like");
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Likes " + menu.getLikes(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        holder.imageMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.wtf("Tuttimenu MyAdapterHome", "Click Image");
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Click Image!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent menuActivity = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), MenuActivity.class);
                menuActivity.putExtra("EXTRA_NAME", menu.getName());
                menuActivity.putExtra("EXTRA_IMAGE", menu.getImagePath());
                menuActivity.putExtra("EXTRA_TYPE", "Menù classico");
                //homeAdmin.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                //homeAdmin.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context,
                        holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageMenu), "imgMenuTransition");
                holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(menuActivity, optionsCompat.toBundle());
                //((Activity)mcontext).finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setTemplateMenu(ViewHolder holder, String name, String shadow, String icon, Menu menu, Resources resources){
        holder.txtLikes.setText(menu.getLikes()+" Likes");
        holder.txtViews.setText(menu.getViews()+" Views");
        Drawable drawableAdsMenu = resources.getDrawable(resources.getIdentifier(shadow,"drawable","com.tuttimenu.app.tuttimenu"));
        holder.imageTypeMenu.setImageResource(resources.getIdentifier(icon,"drawable","com.tuttimenu.app.tuttimenu"));
        holder.bottomCardView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableAdsMenu);
        holder.txTypeMenu.setText(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mTitle, mSubTitle, txtLikes, txtViews, txTypeMenu;
        public ImageView imageMenu, imgCorners, imageTypeMenu;
        public RelativeLayout bottomCardView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            bottomCardView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bottomCardView);
            imageMenu = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageMenu);
            imageTypeMenu = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageTypeMenu);
            imgCorners = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgCorners);
            mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            txtLikes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_likes);
            txtViews = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_views);
            mSubTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            txTypeMenu = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_typeMenu);
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolderADS extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mTitle, mSubTitle, txtLikes, txtViews, txTypeMenu;
        public ImageView imageMenu, imgCorners, imageTypeMenu;
        public RelativeLayout bottomCardView;

        public ViewHolderADS(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            bottomCardView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bottomCardView);
            imageMenu = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageMenu);
            imageTypeMenu = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageTypeMenu);
            imgCorners = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgCorners);
            mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            txtLikes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_likes);
            txtViews = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_views);
            mSubTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            txTypeMenu = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_typeMenu);
        }
    }
}
```

Hi everyone,  first of all I would like to say I'm new to the JAVA programming, I have already done several tests, I have this code (posted below) and I would like to save the position of the MainActivity scroll so that when I return from MenuActivity the page doesn't refresh everytime, where am I wrong?

Comment: Is there any override method called onBackPressed() in your MenuActivity?

Comment: @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent mainActivity = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        mainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mainActivity.putExtra("EXTRA_UPDATE", "true");
        startActivity(mainActivity);
    }

Comment: Comment it. And try to run.

Comment: With your post I solve my problem ... thanks very much